# Register beans automatically in Guava EventBus with Spring IoC

Tags: java, spring, guava, vaadin, event-bus

Let's say I have an interface for language change event in my application (it's based on Vaadin):

```
public interface ILanguageChangeListener{
    @Subscribe onLanguageChange(LanguageChangeEvent event);
}
```

And I have many beans that implements this interface annotated with @Component, thus they are available in Spring IoC. I have also an EventBus bean:

```
<bean id="languageSwitcher" class="com.google.common.eventbus" scope="session" />
```

Now, after getting an instance of any bean from IoC I have to get also an instance of the languageSwitcher and register the newely created bean in it with:

```
languageSwitcher.register(myNewBean);
```

in order to receive this events. Is it possible to somehow tell the IoC that I want to call the register method of the languageSwitcher bean on every new bean that implements the ILanguageChangeListener?

Comment: OK, why not creating a factory bean for your EventBus that gets a injected List of ILanguageChangeListeners and just register them in a loop... its manual, but you don't have to put the code to register the bean inside every instance of ILanguageChangeListener.

Comment: Because I do not have all objects that should listen to this event at the beginning - see my comment to the @mael answer.

Comment: Then maybe a [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) to your ILanguageChangeListener implementations. I'm assuming they are prototype?

Comment: Oh yes, I think this is what I'm looking for. Let me try to implement it and I'll get back with a result.

Comment: I will try too, but of course, my answers get debunked D:

Comment: Oh, gosh, finally did it. LoL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, using a BeanPostProcessor, register every bean of your interface:

```
public class EventBusRegisterBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor,
        ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private EventBus eventBus; // The only event bus i assume...

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {

        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {

        if (bean instanceof ILanguageChangeListener) {
            registerToEventBus(bean);
        }

        return bean;
    }

    private void registerToEventBus(Object bean) {
        this.eventBus.register(bean);
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

Note that if you have many EventBus beans, you should use the `ApplicationContext.getBean(String)` to get the EventBus you need.

I quote from the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html#postProcessAfterInitialization%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29):

> In case of a FactoryBean, this callback will be invoked for both the
>   FactoryBean instance and the objects created by the FactoryBean (as of
>   Spring 2.0). The post-processor can decide whether to apply to either
>   the FactoryBean or created objects or both through corresponding bean
>   instanceof FactoryBean checks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm. Also notice, that when using EventBus for such purpose, you should be aware of that Guava does not use weak references to listeners so they will not be garbage collected as long as they're unregistered. It's a bit tricky when it comes to Spring prototype scope. Problem is described here http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=807 and in my case I have introduced the solution from comment #14.

Comment: Quite interesting, do you have a repo or something with your implementation?

Comment: I have no public repo for this project but as for what I've implemented based on your answer - it looks like this: http://pastebin.com/tX55ih4C

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try to make a generic version to my utilities.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, it is even better (less coupling), instead of implementing a marker interface, to use a class level annotation to mark beans that should be registered. Here is the modified bean post processor code :

```
public class EventBusListenersRegistererBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Inject
    private EventBus bus;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(bean.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(RegisterWithEventBus.class)){
            log.info("Event Bus is registering bean named \"{}\" of class {}.", beanName, bean.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            bus.register(bean);
        }

        return bean;
    }
}
```

And the annotation :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited // important when working with dynamically generated proxies i.e. CGLib
public @interface RegisterWithEventBus {}
```

Note that the annotation interface has the @Inherited meta-annotation. This is necessary in a Spring app that uyses CGLIB proxies, since the annotation will not be on the actual (dynamic) class of the object, but on the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory bean for your event bus and inject a list of all the ILanguageChangeListener beans in your context.

```
public class EventBusFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<EventBus> {

    @Autowired
    private List<ILanguageChangeListener> languageChangeListeners;

    private EventBus instance;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        this.instance = new EventBus();

        for (ILanguageChangeListener listener : this.languageChangeListeners) {
            this.instance.register(listener);
        }
    }

    public EventBusFactoryBean() {

    }

    public EventBus getObject() throws Exception {
        return this.instance;
    }

    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return EventBus.class;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    public List<ILanguageChangeListener> getLanguageChangeListeners() {
        return languageChangeListeners;
    }

    public void setLanguageChangeListeners(
            List<ILanguageChangeListener> languageChangeListeners) {
        this.languageChangeListeners = languageChangeListeners;
    }

}
```

And then define your bean in the Spring Bean Definition file or annotate it with `@Component`

Comment: But you assume that there is a moment in application lifetime when I know all instances of classes implementing ILanguageChangeListener. But this is not true - for example each view in my app implements it but they are not all created during application startup. They are created (pulled from IoC) as the user browse and open new pages (views). So - what I'm looking for is to somehow tell the IoC that before it injects any of the ILanguageChangeListener, it should be registered in the EventBus. Hope I'm clear now.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using the interface [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) and inject the language switcher in your bean. Something like this:

```
public class NotVeryUsefulLanguageListener implements ILanguageChangeListener,
        InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private EventBus languageSwitcher;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        this.languageSwitcher.register(this);
    }

    //... getters, setters, etc

}
```

If `NotVeryUsefulLanguageLisetener` is singleton, it will happen only once... if prototype then every time you get an instance from the Spring

If you are using XML then you can use something like this:

```
<bean id="languageListenerA" init-method="afterPropertiesSet" class="org.company.whatever.NotVeryUsefulLanguageListener">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </bean>
```

Comment: I can use @PostConstruct to have the same effect. This is far from automated as in every implementation I have to call register() manually.

Comment: Ok, so you want them to be registered once by instance of that bean after spring loads them?